# Ajax POST in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I searched my problem but I cannot find any solution.
I guess it's really simple and I missing something really easy...but I'm stucked.

I have an html page with a php generated list of links, like that:

```
<?php    
     $val = "'"my file with spaces.txt"'";
     echo '<a href="javascript:post_filename('.$val.');">click me</a>';
?>
```

Where $val is different each time, depending on a SQL query.
And the file name is showed correctly, since I hover the mouse on the link and I can read on the bottom-left of the browser:

> javascript:post_filename('my file with spaces.txt');

Clicking this link will call this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function post_filename(val){
             $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'myurl.php',
                data: { filename: val },
                type: 'POST'
            });
        }
</script>
```

But clicking on it, does nothing! No errors, just nothing happens.

With the dev tools (F12 on Chrome) I see that it's all ok... just the mypage.php doesn't show... is a page with graphics, part of the site!

I'm stucked... please help me!
Thanks so much

Comment: `data: filename: val,` that is not valid syntax!

Comment: If you're getting a javascript error, and have no way to even see it, you have a more serious problem. Make sure you have some sort of developer tools/console in your browser, or you will never be able to debug js.

Comment: Changed it to:

data: { filename: val },

But still nothing happens. I get no errors: just after the click happens nothing...

Comment: @Luke85 You've not stated what you're expecting to happen. Are you expecting something to appear on the page? So far all you're doing is sending the name of a file to a PHP page.

Comment: Like a POST on a button in a form, I expect that the new page opens, and show me that the POST worked (ie: echo the filename). How can I do that? I feel that I miss something really easy...

Comment: It might help if you post the code of `myfile.php`. AJAX opens a connection to your server and sends the data to the PHP file, but your browser doesn't change page or anything, that's the whole point of AJAX. Whatever you echo out in that file is returned to you browser, but you're not doing anything with that data. You might want to check out [`.done()` examples in the jquery documents](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples).

Comment: You have an incorrect syntax error - `type: 'POST';`, you shouldn't have a semi-colon at the end of the line. This is why you should always use the developer console and check what it says.

Comment: I edited my post with the F12 results. On the other page I have some graphics and this php code:   $filename = ($_POST['filename']); echo $filename;  but I want to open that page after the post, too continue. I'm reading the .done() function but I cannot find any code for "proceed" like a normal click on a button in a form with the post event... ^_^

Comment: You don't proceed like a normal click button on a form, that's the whole point of AJAX. If you want to proceed like a form, use a form.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX call was invalid, `data` should be either a String, Array or Object. Object is probably what you're after here from the start you've made

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function post_filename(val){
             $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'myurl.php',
                data: {
                    filename: val
                },
                type: 'POST';
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors? I'm not sure if your URL would work considering it's full of spaces as well

Comment: You're not wrong, my bad been a LONG morning, I shall edit it now :)

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the AJAX call? Your code only asks it to send the data via AJAX to that URL, says nothing about what should happen after that

Answer (score 0):

Try making data an object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function post_filename(val){
             $.ajax
            ({ 
                url: 'myurl.php',
                data: { filename: val },
                type: 'POST';
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I suspect then your error is on the server, check that side and see how you process in the php side? maybe paste some server side code?

Comment: That's my code; the other code is a simple:

                                $filename = ($_POST['filename']);
                                echo $filename;
                            

that I have in mypage.php

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, but I made some some revisions for it to work ( I just notice you had a **semicolon** after **type**, I believe that should be a comma, that the reason why you have unexpected token) my codes works using this:

```
<?php    
$val = "'hello.txt'";
echo '<a href="#" class="click" file="'.$val.'">click me</a>';
?>
```

---

on javascript

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $.ajax
    ({ 
        url: 'myurl.php',
        data: { filename: $(this).attr('file') },
        type: 'POST'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        //check the output from your url
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But after this, how can I automatically goes on myurl.php and see the page with the variable posted? Because right now the page isn't showing (is a page with graphics, not only code.. is part of the site)

Comment: hi Luke +1 for your question, i edited my answer. Ajax is really use to fetch some data and post it to the same page its not really intended to redirect one page to another page. Before clicking the "click me", on your chrome browser press f12. On the 'console' tab, you can check what will happen if you click the link.  The 'success' part of this code will handle the output from your 'myurl.php'

Comment: `success` and `error` are depreciated. You should use `done` and `fail`. I've updated your answer to show this.